# Remove numbering from fitch.sty natural deduction

Tags: tables, formatting, counters, width, logic

Johan Klüwer has a great package [fitch.sty](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/fitch.sty) for typsetting natural deduction proofs. However I want to define some deduction rules in the vertical fitch format and it does not make sense to have the numbering on the left side since there could be arbitrarily many lines in between the lines with the relevant information. For example, I want to drop the line numbering so that I can indicate that there need not bee exactly one line between the line with A and the line with B:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{fitch}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{fitch}
    \fh A & Hypothesis \\
    \fa \vdots \\
    \fa B & derrived from hypothesis\\
    A \to B
    \end{fitch}
    \end{equation*}

    \end{document}
```

[image: conditional proof]

Comment: Unfortunately, that code is not licensed. So it is impossible to tell what may be done with it, including whether it is permissible to modify, distribute or, even, use it.

Comment: Hypothetically, however, I would suggest `\renewcommand\formatfitchcounter[1]{\relax}` in a local group with the rules you want typeset this way.

Comment: I was looking for [fitch.sty](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/fitch.sty), which is not to be confused with the [fitch package](https://ctan.org/pkg/fitch) on ctan. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Someone must have answered this. Simply use:

```
\begin{fitch*}

\end{fitch*}
```

That will do the trick.
I myself would like to change the numbering and start at n, say. But that is another question.